# how logout facebook c# sdk in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

how logout facebook c# sdk in windows 8?
i use this code but cannot logout

```
      var   logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                                   {"acces_token",App.AccessToken}   , 
                                                   { "next", "http://www.facebook.com" }
      };
      var logoutUrl = _fb.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);
      var logout= WebRequest.Create(logoutUrl);
      await logout.GetResponseAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.DeleteSessionData();